# Can't connect to RDS via AWS.RDS.Signer

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL RDS from a Lambda via `AWS.RDS.Signer` with the following code and `fake` credentials:

```js
1  const DB_REGION = 'ap-southeast-2a'
2  const DB_HOST = 'dbinstance.ddtev8utygt.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
3  const DB_PORT = 3306
4  const DB_USER = 'anyuser'
5  const DB_NAME = 'anydb'
6
7  const signerOptions = {
8    region: DB_REGION,
9    hostname: DB_HOST,
10   port: DB_PORT,
11   username: DB_USER
12 }
13
14 const signer = new AWS.RDS.Signer(signerOptions)
15 const token = await signer.getAuthToken()
16 
17 const config = {
18   host: DB_HOST,
19   user: DB_USER,
20   password: token, // "Password123"
21   database: DB_NAME,
22   ssl: 'Amazon RDS',
23   authPlugins: {
24     mysql_clear_password: () => () => token
25   }
26 }
```

but I always get this error

```js
"Access denied for user 'anyuser'@'172.14.1.12' (using password: NO)"
```

I'm not entirely sure if that is needed for the `AWS.RDS.Signer` but I selected this option of my database:

```js
Password and IAM database authentication
Authenticates using the database password and user credentials through AWS IAM users and roles.
```

**NOTE:** If I swap the password from token to `"Password123"` on `line 20` I can successfully connect to my RDS.

Am I missing something here or does `AWS.RDS.Signer` only work with `RDS Proxy`?

**By the way:** the `getAuthToken` function gives me something like that (token truncated)

`"dbinstance.ddtev8utygt.apsoutheast2.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/Action=connect&DBUser=anyuser&&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAU7VGXF6UCWYZCFEG%2F20210318%2Fap-southeast-2a%2Frds-db%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20210318T105145Z&X-Amz-Expires=900&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAsaDmFwLXNvdXRoZWFzdC0yIkgwRgIhAKg8ibwNJ4E3hSOuq7HtDFvqHxmTlpOUk3I6EH2%2B9VdOV3RQ%2F03xiVdvjhEBkHqEXHQ%3D&X-Amz-Signature=749d931f74873e6c2c0d4fec94f0743f42efd5aa95ca0ac0f05c4bef30e3bd4d&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally can connect to my **RDS** via Lamdba using **IAM** (aka AWS.RDS.Signer)

So what was the problem?

- **Short story:**

I used the wrong region in my **Policy** and in the props for the **AWS.RDS.Signer**.

I assumed that the **Availability zone** (`ap-southeast-2a`) equals the region, but that's not true. The correct region is actually described when the **AWS** command line creds get created. To find out the region invoke `cat ~/.aws/config` from the terminal. My default region was actually `region=ap-southeast-2`.

- **Long story:**

When I started with **AWS.RDS.Signer** I followed the instructions [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/)
When it came to extracting the DB info for the Policy, I used this command

```js
aws rds describe-db-instances --db-instance-identifier <MY INSTANCE NAME> --query "DBInstances[*].DbiResourceId" --region ap-southeast-2a
```

but I got this error `Could not connect to the endpoint URL: "https://rds.ap-southeast-2a.amazonaws.com/"`

After a bit of Googling, I realised that the region is not right. That gave me a hint to change the region in the policy and in the code of my Lambda function.

```json
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "rds-db:connect"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:rds-db:<my-region>:<my-account-id>:dbuser:<my-db-resource-id>/<my-db-username>"
           ]
       }
   ]
}
```

Then I created an extra user (`ssluser`) in the DB to connect with the AWS.RDS.Signer token

```sql
CREATE USER 'ssluser' IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON <MY DB NAME>.* TO 'ssluser'@'%';
GRANT USAGE ON <MY DB NAME>.* TO 'ssluser'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```

The next step was to add the above policy to the **EC2** instance, `ssh` into the instance, install the MySQL client `yum install mysql` and try to connect to the instance using the token

```sh
mysql --host=dbinstance.chteb5kjtggo.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --enable-cleartext-plugin --user=ssluser --password=`aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname dbinstance.chteb5kjtggo.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com --port 3306 --region ap-southeast-2 --username ssluser`
```

After successfully connect to the RDS without providing a password I only had to attach the policy to my **Lambda** and change the username and region in my Lambda code to

```js
1  const DB_REGION = 'ap-southeast-2'
2  const DB_HOST = 'dbinstance.ddtev8utygt.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com'
3  const DB_PORT = 3306
4  const DB_USER = 'ssluser'
5  const DB_NAME = 'anydb'
```

I hope that will help someone in the future.